# Ruby on Rails routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This question has probably been answered multiple times but I am trying to understand the concept and since I am completely new to Ruby on Rails I am hoping someone can explain it to me.

I'm following a tutorial to create a small twitter post app and its asked me to put the following in the route.rb file and run WEBrick to see if its working.

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :posts
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

The problem with that is as soon as I run "rails server" the server starts and after a few seconds exits and give this

> ..RubyProjects/twitter/config/routes.rb:57:in `block in ': uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Routing::Routes
>   (NameError)...

a lot of other errors but I suspect they are all being created by the one above. I am running Ruby 1.9.3p429 and Rails 4.0.0.rc2.

Whiel I was searching for a solution i did realize that this might be caused because I am using syntax from an earlier version which has changed in Rails 4 but I cannot figure out what the correct syntax would be for the new version.

What would the syntax be for a newer version be in this instance?

Comment: If you're following an example that is using old syntax, you're going to have a hell of a time with issues aside from this one. I would recommend a more up to date tutorial such as this one http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

write this line with the lowest priority (last line) in the `config/routes.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:-

```
<yourprojectname>::Application.routes.draw do
resources :products
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```